# Chart.js creating a line graph with date dots

Tags: javascript, charts

I'm trying to build line charts with only dots, that represents list of max dates group by other column.

i already build several charts but non of them implements date data.

example of expected result:

[image]

x - the field that data will group by
y - the max time of each field